# T-SQL SELECT TOP 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm running a query where I want to select the first row from a query result. If I have two rows in the table it will return a result but if I only have one it won't return anything.

```
select TOP 1 u.ID
from [dbo].[User] u
where u.ID <> '5dc89076-e554-42f2-a9ae-787b20f6f56b' AND u.gender != 'male'
except
select [dbo].[Like].likes
from [dbo].[Like]
where [dbo].[Like].[user] = '5dc89076-e554-42f2-a9ae-787b20f6f56b'
except
select [dbo].[Dislike].dislikes
from [dbo].[Dislike]
where [dbo].[Dislike].[user] = '5dc89076-e554-42f2-a9ae-787b20f6f56b'
```

This query returns nothing

```
select u.ID
from [dbo].[User] u
where u.ID <> '5dc89076-e554-42f2-a9ae-787b20f6f56b' AND u.gender != 'male'
except
select [dbo].[Like].likes
from [dbo].[Like]
where [dbo].[Like].[user] = '5dc89076-e554-42f2-a9ae-787b20f6f56b'
except
select [dbo].[Dislike].dislikes
from [dbo].[Dislike]
where [dbo].[Dislike].[user] = '5dc89076-e554-42f2-a9ae-787b20f6f56b'
```

This query returns Id:9EF5B83E-319A-4E2F-88A1-E67227DBFDCE

Comment: `TOP (n)` without an `ORDER BY`  is pointless - what are your rows ordered by, if you want to get the `TOP (n)` of your data?? Unless you specify **WHAT** criteria your data is ordered by - it's totally arbitrary....

Comment: The query searches three tables to find eligible users. Then it just returns the first eligible user. What would be a better way to write it ?

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do - I'm just saying if you don't **explicitly specify** an `ORDER BY`, you're getting the "first" row - ordered by whatever SQL Server might think is OK - you're not getting a specific "first" row - any "first" row ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> select TOP 1 u.ID
> from ...
> except
> ...
> ```

means it first runs the first select, then takes the top 1 result, and finally runs the second and third select to determine what to exclude.

That isn't what you want. You want to run the three queries, exclude rows, and finally take the top 1 result.

One valid syntax for that is

```
select top 1 ID
from (
  select u.ID
  from ...
  except
  ...
) as q
```

There are other approaches that can give the same result, but this is the one I'd go with.

Comment: I echo @marc_s comment. You should really use an `order by` so it isn't arbitrary. Even if the actual field(s) you order by is arbitrary, at least it gives you some certainty as to what record will appear first. (so that when you're debugging an issue you can make some assumptions)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use simple **OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY** keyword

Note: it requires ORDER BY clause.

```
CREATE TABLE #test (
    Id INT,
    Name varchar(50)
)
GO

INSERT INTO #test VALUES
    (1, 'Soda'),
    (2, 'Coke'),
    (3, 'Beer'),
    (4, 'Wine')
GO

SELECT *
FROM #test
ORDER BY Id
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
GO

DROP TABLE #test;
GO
```